# best solution for sending fax in asterisk

Tags: pdf, asterisk, voip, converters, fax

I want to write a script for sending a fax with Asterisk,
but many faxes have an error when sending.
I use Spandsp for Asterisk and I use `gs` for converting PDF to TIFF.
I think it may be a problem of converting PDF to TIFF.
I very try to convert's command for this, such as:

```
 gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg3 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=Sample.pdf.tif -f Sample.pdf
```

---

```
/usr/bin/acroread -toPostScript -size a4 <filename>
/usr/bin/gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg32d -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r204x196 -sOutputFile=<outputfile> -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -f <inputfile.ps>
```

and I tested anyways into [link](http://www.soft-switch.org/spandsp_faq/ar01s14.html) for converting, but it doesn't work fine, and most of sending fax have issue.
Also, I have another problem in answer detection beep in my Asterisk when the trunk with Newrock gateway(analog), this is cause some fax doesn't send correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check hylafax code. It have working script

I use code like this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffg3 -sPAPERSIZE=$pagesize -r204x196 -dNOPAUSE -dNOPAGEPROMPT -dBATCH -sOutputFile=dest.tif \
-c save pop -f input.pdf -c quit
```

But actualy it doesn't metter. More important how setup your routes/codecs.

Other problem is for sure offtopic here. You have read more books or hire expert.

Comment: this is hylafax script [link](http://dave.thehorners.com/content/view/63/65/). I checked it before and I read orielly asterisk and search in google many times but I didn't succeed.
this is my asterisk code:
`[fax-tx-django]
exten => s,n,Answer()
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(ecm)=yes)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(headerinfo)=----> ${FaxHeader}  <----)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(maxrate)=14400)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(minrate)=2400)
exten => s,n,SendDTMF(${FAX_DTMF})
exten => s,n,SendFAX(${FaxName},z)
exten => s,n,Hangup()`

Comment: Use better trunk/provider, turn off compressed codecs. Sorry, debug help is not topic of this site.